# UIScrollView Content of the view is cropped

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, crop

Hi I'm trying to implement a vertical ScrollView, I do it with the StoryBoard, my View Controller is containing a Scroll View which is containing a View (with the content inside):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJAb2.png

When I start my apps the content is cropped, but it's not cropped when I'm editing my storyboard:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI3yo.png

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with your constraint. Post or elaborate your constraint so you can get help from SO.

Comment: How i can post all of the constraints ? @Imran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Center the chidld view in the scroll view, make sure you correctly pin your scrollView

choose:

- add a proportionnal constaint between your view and the firstview
- Or add a trailling and a leading constraint to the scrollView

**NB:** use preview view. Select before your storyboard. This feature help to to see automatic render of your view. You will debug quicly you problem.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why I don't get the same thing in preview view when I run my app...

Comment: I don't have enougth infos for helping you. What you can do is to send us this part of your project. If you can, clean all view in your storyboard, delete unecessary views.